# What is wrong with vectors of Armadillo library

Tags: c++, performance, iteration, armadillo

Previously I posted a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28446563/) which was a bit complicated in some sense. In this question, I made a simple example to generate the same problem with Armadillo library which is supposed to be very fast.

Considering the following code with two main functions only one is activated at each time:

```
#include <armadillo>

const int runmax=50000000;
arma::vec::fixed<3u> x,y;
double a,b;

void init()
{
    x<<0.2<<arma::endr<<-0.3<<arma::endr<<0.1;
    y<<1<<arma::endr<<1<<arma::endr<<1;
    a=0.3;
    b=a*a;
}

template<unsigned N>
void scaledsum(double a,arma::vec::fixed<N> &x,double b,arma::vec::fixed<N> &y)
{
    for(int i=0;i<N;i++)
    {
        y(i)=a*x(i)+b*y(i);
    }
}

void main1()
{

    for(int i=0;i<runmax;i++)
    {
        y=a*x+b*y;
    }
}

void main2()
{
    for(int i=0;i<runmax;i++)
    {
        scaledsum(a,x,b,y);
    }
}

int main()
{
    init();

    //main1();
    main2();
    y.print();
    return 0;
}
```

> perf stat ./main1
>
> perf stat ./main2

I expect main1 runs faster than main2. or at least very close to it. But main1 runs slower.

I do not understand such profiling:

main1

> 0.209682235 seconds time elapsed

main2

> 0.121644777 seconds time elapsed

**PS**
Compilation command: `g++ -std=c++11 -O3 -s -DNDEBUG test.cpp`

Comment: Could you check the generated assembly? Could be that the compiler optimized the loop away completely in one case and not the other. (Looks a bit strange, but 1ms is pretty short.)

Comment: @Mat, main1.asm: http://pastebin.com/9BhwzqCW and main2.asm: http://pastebin.com/GspuzbqC

Comment: Well, look at `main2` in that dump. Also look at the reference-ness of your arguments to `scaledsum`. I don't know that library, but looks like you're passing them by value, and the compiler correctly determines that that function has no side-effects.

Comment: @Mat when i change `main2` to be by reference `void scaledsum(double a,arma::vec::fixed<N> &x,double b,arma::vec::fixed<N> &y)`, it will become much slower `0.120314111 seconds time elapsed`. while it must be much faster. What is wrong?

Comment: That 1ms timing you got is for code that does absolutely nothing (well, not quite - it does go through the loop apparently, just doesn't do anything in the body), i.e. your two programs didn't do the same thing at all. Add something to validate your calculations in `main` to make sure you're testing what you think you are.

Comment: @Mat thank you very much. You referred to a great point. Now the profiling is with 50% difference. I updated the question and here are main1.asm http://pastebin.com/8yZMvyzJ and main2.asm http://pastebin.com/jqhAFqL4

Comment: Assembly without compiler optimization: main1.asm http://pastebin.com/DwEW5wZg main2.asm http://pastebin.com/qd4h2XPU

Comment: Armadillo does size and bound checks by default whenever executing compound operations. For normal matrices the overhead is minimal, but for tiny vectors the overhead of the checks can be noticeable. To to disable the size and bounds checks, define [ARMA_NO_DEBUG](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#config_hpp_arma_no_debug) before including the armadillo header.

Comment: @mtall thank you very much for this great point. It worked for my other question but it did not work for this example. Even though my main problem is fixed now. still I am interested in understanding of solution of this case too.